# Android: Custom layout question

Tags: android, view, android-layout

I'm trying to create a layout in android with program guide data represented by clickable custom shapes/buttons. Here is the project I'm extending on: http://remotepotatoforums.fatattitude.com/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=51 (second image).
I'm fetching the guide data at runttime with a http request. I'm not sure what's the best way to go about this. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? What isn't working? How else would you fetch the guide data? How are we supposed to know what the best way to do this is?

Comment: Actually I'm pulling the data from parsed xml i get from the http response, I have no issues with that. My question was on the layout of the boxes that represent that data. Basically, how do I get the boxes in a table layout/ listview to get as close as i can to that image.